# Styling OpenStreetMap Data for Custom Maps

Tags: openstreetmap, style, vector-tiles, hosting

I'm relatively new to the mapping world and I'm confused about several points.

I'm currently working on a project, which is a mobile app that uses maps. Regarding the map, you can imagine it to be similar to that of Pokémon Go.

I've already tried services like Mapbox and MapTiler and they work fine, but their pricing is too expensive for the project I'm working on. So, I don't intend to use these services but rather have my own map that I distribute to my users.

I understand that the map of the entire world can be downloaded and used for free from OpenStreetMap, put it inside PostgreSQL and served to the user, but what I don't understand is how I can then style that same map so that i serve a stylized version of it?

For example, I've seen that with [Maputnik](https://maplibre.org/maputnik), it's possible to customize the style of the map but once I've downloaded the style, how do I apply it to the world map downloaded from OSM, and then serve this stylized map to my users?

Comment: You need a renderer (+ your stylesheet) to create a map (raster tiles or a vector map) from raw OSM data.